# I'm uppercasing too many elements in my for loop but only on specific indexes

Tags: java, arrays, string, for-loop, uppercase

I don't know why but in this method the 5th and 10th element are being uperCased every time.
I can't find a reason as to why.
for example: Passing "ZpglnRxqenU" as an argument should return: "Z-Pp-Ggg-Llll-Nnnnn-Rrrrrr-Xxxxxxx-Qqqqqqqq-Eeeeeeeee-Nnnnnnnnnn-Uuuuuuuuuuu" but instead returns: "Z-Pp-Ggg-Llll-Nnnnn-RRRRRR-Xxxxxxx-Qqqqqqqq-Eeeeeeeee-Nnnnnnnnnn-UUUUUUUUUUU"

Note that R and U are all uppercased unlike the rest of the characters.

```
/**
 * The purpose of this method is to receive a string, deconstruct it by characters
 * and save it in array, then iterate through this array creating a new string
 * where each character will be represented the number of times equivalent to its
 * position in the array + 1 while upperCasing every 1st occurrence of the character
 * and separating every set of character repetitions with "-".
 * @param string
 * @return String
 */
public String builder (String string){

    /*
    Here we split the string we receive by characters and save these characters in
    a new array called strArr.
     */
    String[] strArr = string.split("");
    String finalString = "";

    /*
    We iterate through the array of characters adding "-" each time we start to
    represent a new character.
    We add the characters N times where N is the order of appearance in the string
    we receive as param.
     */
    for (int i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
        if(i > 0){
            finalString += "-";
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++) {
            if(j == 0){
                /*
                this is upperCasing every 5th and 10th character for some reason
                 */
                // TODO: 26/12/2019 stop upperCasing 5th and 10th element. 
                finalString += strArr[i].toUpperCase();
                continue;
            }
            finalString += strArr[i];
        }
    }
    return finalString;
```

Comment: Because the `R` and `U` are in caps in the source string. You need to convert to lower case.

Comment: "*`// TODO: 26/12/2019 stop upperCasing 5th and 10th element.`*" - I do not know why, but I laughed so hard about this . Just replace `finalString += strArr[i];` with `finalString += strArr[i].toLowerCase();` and you will be fine.

Comment: Ahhhh. Obviously. Damn. Ahahaha

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OPs code does exactly what it is supposed to do - the problem was in understanding the  requirements.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add this line at first:
string = string.toLowerCase();

public String builder (String string){

```
 string = string.toLowerCase();
/*
Here we split the string we receive by characters and save these characters in
a new array called strArr.
 */
String[] strArr = string.split("");
String finalString = "";

/*
We iterate through the array of characters adding "-" each time we start to
represent a new character.
We add the characters N times where N is the order of appearance in the string
we receive as param.
 */
for (int i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
    if(i > 0){
        finalString += "-";
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++) {
        if(j == 0){
            /*
            this is upperCasing every 5th and 10th character for some reason
             */
            // TODO: 26/12/2019 stop upperCasing 5th and 10th element. 
            finalString += strArr[i].toUpperCase();
            continue;
        }
        finalString += strArr[i];
    }
}
return finalString;
```

}